# Getting 'ActivityManager? Unable to retrieve gids' on app resume

Tags: android

I got the following exception on resuming the app.

- Unable to get package info for com.mypackage; is package not installed?
  Can anybody help me to understand why this could occur?

Could this be due to the app being killed by the OS?

```
    08-12 17:30:08.411      588-612/? W/PackageManager? Not granting permission android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS to package com.mypackage (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x83e46)
    08-12 17:30:08.411      588-612/? W/PackageManager? Not granting permission android.permission.READ_LOGS to package com.mypackage (protectionLevel=50 flags=0x83e46)
    08-12 17:30:08.491      588-612/? I/ActivityManager? Force stopping com.mypackage appid=10100 user=0: pkg removed
    08-12 17:30:08.731      588-588/? D/BackupManagerService? Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.mypackage flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
    08-12 17:30:08.741      588-588/? D/BackupManagerService? Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.mypackage flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
    08-12 17:30:09.592     588-6079/? I/ActivityManager? START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mypackage/.android.ui.mypackageMainActivity} from pid 14822
    08-12 17:30:09.602      588-890/? I/ActivityManager? Start proc com.mypackage for activity com.mypackage/.android.ui.MainActivity: pid=14842 uid=10100 gids={50100, 3003, 1028, 1015}
    08-12 17:30:17.120     588-7406/? I/ActivityManager? START u0 {cmp=com.mypackage/.android.ui.chat.ActivityMessage (has extras)} from pid 14842
    08-12 17:30:21.013      588-891/? I/ActivityManager? START u0 {cmp=com.mypackage/.android.ui.chat.InviteMember (has extras)} from pid 14842
    08-12 17:32:25.665      588-612/? W/ActivityManager? No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.mypackage
    08-12 17:32:26.946      588-612/? W/ActivityManager? No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.mypackage
    08-12 17:32:28.067      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Force stopping com.mypackage appid=10100 user=-1: uninstall pkg
    08-12 17:32:28.067      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Killing 14842:com.mypackage/u0a100 (adj 0): stop com.mypackage
    08-12 17:32:28.067      588-604/? W/ActivityManager? Force removing ActivityRecord{429f2ee8 u0 com.mypackage/.android.ui.chat.InviteMember t127}: app died, no saved state
    08-12 17:32:28.077      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{4247baa0 u0 com.mypackage/.android.ui.MainActivity t127}
    08-12 17:32:28.117      588-854/? I/WindowState? WIN DEATH: Window{423df988 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.android.ui.MainActivity}
    08-12 17:32:28.117     588-7406/? I/WindowState? WIN DEATH: Window{423fe800 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.android.ui.chat.InviteMember}
    08-12 17:32:28.117      588-615/? I/WindowState? WIN DEATH: Window{423f9df8 u0 com.mypackage/com.mypackage.android.ui.chat.ActivityMessage}
    08-12 17:32:28.257      588-612/? I/PackageManager? Package com.mypackage codePath changed from /data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk to /data/app/com.mypackage-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
    08-12 17:32:28.257      588-604/? W/ActivityManager? Unable to retrieve gids
        android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.mypackage
                at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageGids(ApplicationPackageManager.java:143)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:2706)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:2673)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1074)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1660)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1247)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishCurrentActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2529)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2462)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityStack.java:3409)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1970)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4655)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$300(ActivityManagerService.java:203)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$2.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1330)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1870)
    08-12 17:32:28.287      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Start proc com.mypackage for activity com.mypackage/.android.ui.chat.ActivityMessage: pid=15098 uid=10100 gids={50100}
    08-12 17:32:28.287      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{424a3d70 u0 com.mypackage/.android.ui.chat.ActivityMessage t127}
    08-12 17:32:28.297      588-604/? I/ActivityManager? Force stopping service ServiceRecord{4285e0f8 u0 com.mypackage/.xmpp.XMPPService}
    08-12 17:32:28.398  15098-15098/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.mypackage, PID: 15098
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.mypackage; is package not installed?
                at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.mypackage; is package not installed?
                at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:376)
                at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329)
                at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: greping a logcat with ActivityManager provide u activity which is currently visible so when the app crashs that activity must be cause for  the same